# SQL:How to keep inserting record number in the target table in INSERT INTO statement

Tags: sql-server

I have query like this:

```
 declare @guidd nvarchar(10)
        set @guidd = '11233'
        create table rrr_temp(value nvarchar(10), value2 int)
        create table rrr_tempA(valueA nvarchar(10), guidd nvarchar(10), ranks int)
        insert into rrr_temp values('AAA', 200)
        insert into rrr_temp values ('BBB', 400)
        insert into rrr_temp values ('CCC', 300)

        INSERT INTO rrr_tempA(valueA , guidd , ranks )
            SELECT RT.value, @guidd , row_number() over (order by (select NULL))
            FROM rrr_temp(nolock) RT
            INNER JOIN 
                (SELECT value, min(value2) AS lastLeg
                FROM rrr_temp(nolock) RTL               
                GROUP BY value) GrpRoute 
            ON RT.value = GrpRoute.value
            ORDER BY value2
            select * from rrr_tempA
```

With the above INSERT iNTO statement, i am able to insert only the record number of source table(rrr_temp) for 'ranks' column of Target table by using 'row_number() over (order by (select NULL))'. But, i want the number to be incremented when target table got inserted. i cannot use IDENTITY. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do here. Why can't you use identity? And what is the point of the NOLOCK hint? It isn't possible that table could be locked, you created it right before you query it. If you are going to use hints you should include the WITH keyword, Omitting it is deprecated. And why not use temp tables instead of persistent tables that act like temp tables. You might want to take a look at this article before you continue splattering that hint everywhere. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: if you don't want to use identities, you can put a sub query in your select that gets the current max key value, then increments it.  here you need to do something like MAX(ranks) + row_number() over...

Comment: With the above query, the target table data is:( 'AAA', 200, 1),( 'CCC', 300, 3),( 'BBB', 400, 2). But my expected output should be ::( 'AAA', 200, 1),( 'CCC', 300, 2),( 'BBB', 400, 3). Hope it gives clarity. Ranks column is displaying 1,3,2...but i want it like 1, 2,3.

Comment: These RANKING should be done GUIDD wise. So, we cannot use MAX of the column or IDENTITY.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about something like this?

```
select @max_rank = max(ranks)
from rrr_tempA

set @max_rank = IsNull(@max_rank, 0)

INSERT INTO rrr_tempA(valueA , guidd , ranks )
SELECT RT.value, @guidd , @max_rank + row_number() over (order by (select NULL))
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But, I want the records in target as follows: ('AAA', 200, 1),('CCC', 300, 2),('BBB', 400, 3). These RANKING should be done GUIDD wise. So, we cannot use MAX of the column.

Comment: "GUIDD wise" - no idea what you mean.